# How to get max <li> width from <ul> for each "column"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## Intro

Hi there,

I have a table made with lists `<ul>` that [looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Dcd7R/).

As you can see, I have added `getMaxLiWidth()` to achieve the biggest `<li>` width for all.

## Before

`#`|`Name`|`Extra`

`1`|`This is a very big name`|`Extra`

## What I want

`#`|`Name`                                      |`Extra`

`1`|`This is a very big name`|`Extra`

## What I get

`#`                                      |`Name`                                      |`Extra`

## Question

How do I need to change my `getMaxLiWIdth()` to get the max width for each "column"?

Comment: any reason why you dont use actual table markup?

Comment: @user1721135 Because fixed header don't work in IE7

Comment: i would use a sepperate table as header in this case. not sure what you are trying to do with getmaxwidth... im thinking you wouldnt need any js with tables

Comment: check this http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html

Comment: Separate tables is a better solution. Using JavaScript for styling is never a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the css for all the list items in the widest column. First you have to identify the widest column, then return it with the max width, then use it as part of the selector.

```
function getMaxLiWidth() {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    var column = 0;
    $('li').each(function() {
        if (this.offsetWidth > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = this.offsetWidth;
            column = $(this).index();
            console.log(column);
        }
    });
    return [maxWidth,column];
}

$(function() {

    var arr = getMaxLiWidth();
    $('li:nth-child(' + (arr[1] + 1) + ')').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            'width': arr[0]
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Dcd7R/2/

Answer (score -1):

You need to put different format for each column here. Simply try CSS

Comment: I don't know how big my content will be. So CSS width I cannot use.

Comment: its fine but you can use % in this case.

Comment: If I use % I need to know how much columns I have. But I don't know since the content is dynamic.

Comment: I don't think so function getMaxLiWIdth() work here if all columns are dynamic you need to use XML and XSLT or any other option.